# How can I catch a exception form ObjectDataSource.Updata()

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, objectdatasource

The exception is throwed by database caused a conflicting by FOREIGN KEY.

Answer (score 4):

look at the eventargs on the ObjectDataSource.  There should be an e.Exception & e.Results that you can query for the success/error of your update.

```
protected void MyOds_Updated(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        // handle exception here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
But I found that my problem is still exist. The exception occur on the Update-event while the Updated-method has not responded. Must I override the ObjectDataSource.Update() or ObjectDataSourceView ?

Answer (score 3):

To tell the ObjectDataSource to not rethrow your exception, you have to set the **ExceptionHandled** flag to True.

```
protected void MyOds_Updated(object sender, ObjectDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {

        //this tells the ObjectDatasource : It's ok, i'm taking care of this
        //and don't rethrow it.
        e.ExceptionHandled = true

        // handle exception here (log/display to user etc ...)
    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Manitra.

Answer (score 0):

if this is not helping use the grid view update method

```
If Not e.Exception Is Nothing Then
    e.KeepInEditMode = True
    e.ExceptionHandled = True
    msg("error .", "a", Me.GetType(), ClientScript)
End If
```